# JSON schema - how to use oneOf

Tags: json, jsonschema

The following is a valid JSON schema according to http://jsonlint.com/ and http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["results"],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "results": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
                { "result": "1" },
                { "result": "2" },
                { "result": "3" },
                { "result": "4" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The following JSON reports an error (`results is the wrong type`) when validated against the above schema:

```
{
    "results" : {
        "result": "1"
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I might resolve this error?

Comment: works for me agains the validator http://s4.postimg.org/dysqmvn4t/Screen_Shot_2015_05_18_at_10_52_08.png

Comment: What I'm saying is that the JSON is valid but does not conform to the schema. Are you saying otherwise?

Answer (score 28):

It looks like what you want in this case is `enum` rather than `oneOf`.  Here is how you would define your schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["results"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "results": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "result": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, the question was how to use `oneOf` properly.  The `oneOf` keyword should be an array of schemas, not values as you have used in your example.  One and only one of the schemas in `oneOf` must validate against the data for the `oneOf` clause to validate.  I have to modify your example a little to illustrate how to use `oneOf`.  This example allows `result` to be a string or an integer.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["results"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "results": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "result": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
            },
            {
              "type": "integer",
              "minimum": 1,
              "maximum": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`results` is a type of `object` as per you schema definition but you mentioned type as `String`. If I change the type as `object`, It just works fine.

Comment: This answer fixes the error that was reported, but the usage of `oneOf` is incorrect as well.  With this change only, the value of `result` would not actually be constrained to 1-4.